# Shifting control between compiled matlab code

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

So I have two pieces of compiled matlab code(in exe). I want the follwping behaviour:

One exe file(exefile1) calls the other, using 'system('exefile2')'. The other file(exefile2) runs and after completing its functionality, returns control to the calling file(exefile1). But for some reason, the exefile2 does not return the control, but rather just completes and returns to command promt. Is their a way to acheive what I want?

Answer (score 0):

You did not put many details in your description, but I tried the following and it worked fine.

First script (hello.m):

```
try
    disp('hello');
    system('hi.exe');
    disp('hello');
catch
    fprintf('%s', exc.getReport('extended'))
end
```

Second script (hi.m):

```
try
    disp('hi')
catch
    fprintf('%s', exc.getReport('extended'))
end
```

The try-catch is a bit unnecessary here, but it always help when compiling stuff. Anyway, the basic idea is:

```
hello starts
hello prints hello
hello starts hi
hi prints hi and returns
hello prints hello again
end
```

I compiled both scripts as **Console Application** and run it on a command prompt and it works fine:

```
hello
hi
hello
```

So I am not sure what your specific problem is, but the basic idea works fine...